# How to fix this weird error in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I write a calculator then I tried to write a shorter version and there is one part of the code isn't working as I need:

```
import os
while True:
  cont = input('Do you want to continue? (y for yes or n for no)\n')
  os.system('clear') if os.name == 'posix' else os.system('cls') if cont == 'Y' or cont == 'y' else break if cont == 'N' or cont == 'n' else print('That's not y or n!')
```

And this is the longer version:

```
import os
while True:
  cont = input('Do you want to continue? (y or n)\n')
  if cont == 'Y' or cont == 'y':
    if os.name == 'posix':
      os.system('clear')
    else:
      os.system('cls')
  elif cont == 'N' or cont == 'n':
    break
  else:
    print('That's not y or n!')
```

Sorry for not commenting anything!

I can't do anything to the `break` at there because I've put the code into a `while True:` loop. I tried put in the `i = 1` then change the `while True:` to `while i = 1:` and changed the `break` to `i = 0` but it gives even more errors.

Comment: “Weird error”. Care to share the error please? “Even more errors”.  Care to share those as well? Full traceback please.

Comment: The first error is "Expected expression" (the original shorthand code) and the second one is "Expression cannot be assignment target" (after the change).

Comment: Do not minimize working code in order to create unreadable one liners.

Comment: The last line is mistake..This is correct: print(" That's not y or n! "). Be careful with single and double quotes usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily shrink down your your code and keep it readable:

```
import os
cont = input('Do you want to continue? (y or n)\n').lower()
if cont == 'y':
    cmd = "clear" if os.name == 'posix' else "cls"
    os.system(cmd)
elif cont not in ('n', 'y'):
    print('That's not y or n!')
else: # if needed
    break
```

Comment: The `cont = input('Do you want to continue? (y or n)\n').lower()` is actually great! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add `break`, there should be a loop (like for or while). If you want to exit from the program if user input 'n' or 'N', you can do something like this.

```
elif cont == 'N' or cont == 'n':
    exit
```

Since there is no loop to break, you can simply remove this `elif` snippet and handle not inserting 'n' or 'N' or 'y' or 'Y' like this.

```
elif cont != 'N' or cont != 'n':
    print("That's not 'n' or 'y'")
```